# Parallel execution of COM instances in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlabpool

I'm trying to accelerate our test environment by using the ParralelToolbox of Mathworks. However I am unable to start several Matlab instances in parallel (up to now we run our tests sequentially and each one is starting a new Matlab instance via an ActX server).
So when I run the following code below

```
ML=ver('Matlab');
ML_Path=matlabroot;
ML_Ver=ML.Version;
parfor i = 1:3
    NewMatlab = actxserver(['matlab.application.single.',ML_Ver])
    Answer = NewMatlab.Feval('test',1);
    NewMatlab.Quit;
    NewMatlab.release;
end
```

the Matlab instances are called sequentially (test is just a very simple script that sums up a few numbers).

However if I start a new Matlab via command line

```
ML=ver('Matlab');
ML_Path=matlabroot;
ML_Ver=ML.Version;
parfor i = 1:3
    dos('matlab -nodesktop -minimize -wait -batch "test"');
end
```

it works. I see that these two methods are quite different in the handling of starting Matlab, but the first approach would be

Answer (score 1):

If you want each iteration of your `test` to run in a completely separate MATLAB instance, you could use the [`batch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/batch.html) function, like this:

```
for i = 1:3
    j(i) = batch(@test, nOut, {argsIn...});
end
% Later, collect results
for i = 1:3
    wait(j(i)), fetchOutputs(j(i))
end
```

Or, you could simply use `parfor` directly

```
parpool() % If necessary
parfor i = 1:3
    out{i} = test(...)
end
```

(You only need to call `parpool` if no pool is currently open, and you have your preferences set so that a pool is not automatically created when you hit the `parfor`).

Comment: Well, what we are intend to do is impelementing a parallel execution of our Simulink tests. Currently we start a new Matlab instance via ActiveX for each test and run the tests sequentially. The background is that if one test leads to a Matlab crash (yes, this happens quite often...) we still can test the other models. `parfor` uses the same workspace for all iterations; this won't work because each test has it's own environment and `batch` might mabye work, but it does not solve the stability problem that we avoid with seperate Matlab instances...

Comment: `batch` does use separate MATLAB worker processes for each task.